# What weapons and equipment are practical for Counterinsurgency?

Tags: warfare, weapons

I am writing about a fictional Private Military Company, (PMC) devoted to Counter-terrorism . Because I am in doubt of what to have my counter-insurgents  be issued, their loadouts, and what equipment that they would use.

What modern Military weapons vehicles and equipment would be best for fighting terrorists?

these must be already existing modern weapons, military vehicles, and equipment that are in current use with world militaries of existing governments. And everything modern.

[Clarification]

the PMC here is a fictional Private Military Company devoted to counter-terrorism via both charity work and military operations in assistance to Third World Nation States that cannot afford a standing army.

and Like in real life, this actually does occur, and is done often by third world nations to combat terrorism within their boarders.

Comment: Ever read the Carrera series by Tom Kratman? Book 1 was basically Carrera waging a full counter insurgency campaign against the Salafists who killed his wife and his children with a terrorist strike.

Comment: "PMC" probably means "Private Military Company." PMCs use a variety of weapons and equipment depending on what they know about the situation or circumstance. "Counterinsurgency" is way too broad to meet the expectations of this site (see our [help]). This site's purpose is to help you develop the rules and systems of your fictional world. It is beyond the scope of the site to help you develop the details of a story, which this is (the Q is about circumstances and character choices, not rules and systems).

Comment: Before 2001, the term "terrorist" had a limited and useful definition. Similarly, "counter-terrorism" before 2001 meant a specific set of limited operations. Since 2001, misuse has ruined the terms' usefulness: "terrorist" is now merely a synonym for "bad person" and "counter-terrorism" can refer to almost any kind of fight. So when this question asks about "fighting terrorists," it's very unclear what is intended.